# Can I travel to Germany for a job interview with no current status in Oman?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, oman

I have got 2-years visa til September 2019.

My current contract has expired 2 weeks ago. But the documents have already been submitted to the ministry for the one-year extension.

I am uncertain of my current status in Oman after the expiry of my contract.

I want to visit Germany for a Job Interview in 2-3 weeks. Since my contract has expired, is there any issue to get a Visa for Germany? Is there any requirement of German (or any other European) Embassy to submit the Current Employer Contract (the current status in Oman) with the application form?
And if the German Embassy ask me to submit the leave application (or NOC) from the current employer, what should be my answer in that case?

Comment: A) One question per post, please (although 2. & 3. probably are just part of the same). B) Question 1 belongs to https://expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: You ask a lot of questions many of which could be answered just through reading availbale documents and your own residence permit condition.

Comment: @TomasBy the contract is already expired on 28 December 2017. But we are waiting for the approval to renew it.

Comment: I guess the main issue is if your Omani visum is multiple-entry or tied to the employment, but that has nothing to do with Germany.

Comment: @TomasBy you are right, but I have seen the required documents for visa application and one of the documents they need is (No objection letter by the applicant’s
sponsor in Oman (only for non-Omanis)).

Comment: Yes, it [seems](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/germany-visa/) to be more complicated than I thought. Maybe you can call the German consulate and ask them. When I applied for a visum in a somewhat similar situation they barely glanced at the letter from my employer.

Comment: @TomasBy ok one more thing if you know, if have two interviews in Germany and Netherlands, can I both give in one visit? I just go to Germany and from there I go to Netherlands? is it possible?

Comment: In practice you can just go, and I think in theory also, as the visa are for the whole Schengen area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71457/discussion-between-furqan-and-tomas-by).

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the one about status in Oman, which isn't appropriate for this site, and left the one about visiting Germany, which is.

Comment: However you do need to tell us your citizenship.

Comment: Yes, it's Pakistan. I updated the question, my last question was, should I just leave Oman and apply to German Embassy there? In that case, I won't have any issue I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only going to answer the question about visiting Germany. The status of your Oman visa is off topic here.

The good news is that in theory you can visit Germany for business purposes on a standard Schengen visitor visa. Business purposes include interviewing for a job (but not of course *doing* a job).

The bad news is that to convince Germany to grant you a visa (which I will assume you need - if your citizenship allows you to travel visa-free to Germany nothing I say here applies) you need to convince them of two things: 1) that you have the financial means to support yourself while in Germany and 2) that you will leave the country when you have done what you came to Germany for.

I will assume that you have the financial means to travel to Germany, stay there for the duration of the interview and leave again. If you don't (and you can't persuade the company asking for the interview to pay all expenses) then there is little point in applying.

The second is much more of a problem. You currently have no job in Oman (and I presume no family). You aren't sure if you have a valid visa to stay there. From the point of view of the immigration officer you have very little reason to return to Oman or anywhere else. It's not even clear if you would be *allowed* to return to Oman. They will assume you are likely to 'go underground' after you arrive in Germany, and this will probably mean they refuse to give you a visa. Not being able to show that you have a current employer is a major part of this problem.

There are things you can do to make this better. If you can prove that you are legally allowed to return to Oman (by getting your visa status sorted out), and show that you have ties to Oman (such as having a job or family there) you improve your chances. You could attempt to show that you have ties to another country, which you would return to afterwards, but this will be difficult since by living in Oman you have demonstrated that you have few ties to other countries.

Comment: Thank you very much @DJClayworth for your valuable points. It turns out that I have a work visa for two years, so it doesn't matter even if the contract is expired, I can still get NOC from my employer.

Comment: Even with a work permit you may find that not having a job is a disadvantage, as you have little reason to return to Oman after the interview.

Comment: I understand your point. How about the NOC letter? There is one required document for a Business Visa which is a letter from current employer or NOC from a current employer. Since I am going to Germany for a Job interview, do I really need to get a NOC or any letter from my current Employer? My Principle Investigator (PI) and the University will not give me any letter for the purpose of Job Interview, (why would they give me, it doesn't make any sense) so in that case, what document do I need to submit instead of NOC or current employer letter. Any idea?

Comment: If the system says you need one, then you need one. You don't have to tell your employer that you are going for a job interview. Just say you are going for personal reasons. But you are better off asking a separate question.

Comment: Ok, I will ask a separate question. For asking any letter from the employer, they need a purpose of visit and full details about the visit. So, can't hide anything.